# Logistic Map on unbounded domains

Tags: chaos-theory

A lot of natural phenomena can be modeled with [Logistic Map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html) or a similar map as they universally show transition to chaos. Logistic Map maps bounded [0,1] -> [0,1] intervals. **Is there an analog with the same CHAOS typical behavior but for unbounded [-∞,∞] -> [-∞,∞] intervals?** I derived a few but they seem too complex. Anyone knows some simpler cases? The reason I am asking is that in reality unbounded intervals / domains / values happen more naturally. I know I can map/rescale infinite to bound values, but **I want to see what is the simplest analytic formula for unbound domains reproducing Logistic Map universal "transition to chaos" behavior.**

### Example of derivation: Tanh

Basic idea is to use Logistic Map formula but to map between [0,1] and [-∞,∞] before and at the end of iteration. This is a kink mapping [-∞,∞]->[0,1]:

$$\frac{\tanh (x)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Substitute to logistic map and simplify (Wolfram Language code):

```
a z (1 - z) /. z -> 1/2 + Tanh[x]/2 // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{1}{4} a \text{sech}^2(x)$$

Now substitute back into the inverse function taking back [0,1]->[-∞,∞]:

```
ArcTanh[2 z - 1] /. z -> 1/4 a Sech[x]^2 // FullSimplify
```

$$\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(a \text{sech}^2(x)-2\right)\right)$$

Here is how it looks and it does seem to work properly. But this looks a bit convoluted. **Any simpler analytic formulas for unbounded Logistic Map showing same CHAOS behavior, for instance leading to Feigenbaum Constant?** Logistic Map behavior is universal and will be found in any similar map. So I guess modifications of Logistic Map or bound<->unbound mapping are OK if we recover bifurcation diagrams, chaos, Feigenbaum Constant, etc, on unbound domains.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, would $x_{n+1}=\lambda \sin(\pi x_n)$ count?

Comment: @AndersSandberg thanks for the idea, but it maps [-∞,∞]->[-,] and I am looking for [-∞,∞]->[-∞,∞] with a simple formula where constant parameter are not infinite, like the one I derived in my question but much simpler, as simple as original logistic map.